# Routing does not work for Django on Azure Function

Tags: django, azure, azure-functions

I have a Django App and I'm trying to migrate the app into Azure Function. But seems like sub routes always return 404. Can someone please help with this?

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path(FUNCTION_APP_PATH + '/admin/' , admin.site.urls),
]
```

setting.py

```
FUNCTION_APP_PATH = 'api/app'
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route ": "app/{*route}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init**.py

```
import azure.functions as func

from config.wsgi import application

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
   return func.WsgiMiddleware(application).handle(req, context)
```

Web Page output

```
No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:7071/api/app/admin/
HTTP ERROR 404
```